# How to make a free hand shape(random) on an image in python using opencv

Tags: python, opencv

To apply boundary fill in a region i need to draw a free hand shape(random) using mouse in python-opencv

Comment: What type of random shape do you want to draw ?

Comment: **any shape-rectangle,circle,or any irregular shapes**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You asked how to draw any giver random shape on a picture using your computer's mouse. Here is a simple solution:

First, you will need to design a method that enables you to draw.  So let's inspire ourselves from [*OpenCV: Mouse as a Paint-Brush*](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_mouse_handling/py_mouse_handling.html) where a method is used to draw common regular shapes such as a circle or a rectangle using a mouse. In your case, you will need random drawing as you could do with your hand.

So using that method you can draw points using the mouse and perform an [*interpolation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation) between them using [`cv2.line()`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html#line) method:

```
cv2.line(im,(current_former_x,current_former_y),(former_x,former_y),(0,0,255),5)
```

Where `im` is the image you read and while you must memorize the former coordinates of the mouse position all the time:

```
current_former_x = former_x
current_former_y = former_y
```

## Full OpenCV program:

Here is the code. Do not hesitate to comment anything you wouldn't understand:

```
'''
Created on Apr 3, 2016

@author: Bill BEGUERADJ
'''
import cv2
import numpy as np 

drawing=False # true if mouse is pressed
mode=True # if True, draw rectangle. Press 'm' to toggle to curve

# mouse callback function
def begueradj_draw(event,former_x,former_y,flags,param):
    global current_former_x,current_former_y,drawing, mode

    if event==cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        drawing=True
        current_former_x,current_former_y=former_x,former_y

    elif event==cv2.EVENT_MOUSEMOVE:
        if drawing==True:
            if mode==True:
                cv2.line(im,(current_former_x,current_former_y),(former_x,former_y),(0,0,255),5)
                current_former_x = former_x
                current_former_y = former_y
                #print former_x,former_y
    elif event==cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONUP:
        drawing=False
        if mode==True:
            cv2.line(im,(current_former_x,current_former_y),(former_x,former_y),(0,0,255),5)
            current_former_x = former_x
            current_former_y = former_y
    return former_x,former_y    



im = cv2.imread("darwin.jpg")
cv2.namedWindow("Bill BEGUERADJ OpenCV")
cv2.setMouseCallback('Bill BEGUERADJ OpenCV',begueradj_draw)
while(1):
    cv2.imshow('Bill BEGUERADJ OpenCV',im)
    k=cv2.waitKey(1)&0xFF
    if k==27:
        break
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

## Demo:

[image]

Comment: **return former_x,former_y---- I didn't understand the use of this statement**

Comment: they are the previous coordinates of the mouse just before you move the mouse  to the following point of the image. Look to the definition of the method: we return `former_x` and `former_y` because they are reused over and over as long as you draw. Try to run the program

Comment: **how can i access a pixel inside this region??**

Comment: I can not post code as a comment and that's an other problem. Ask that in a new question and may be I (or someone else) will answer you.

Comment: @BillalBegueradj It seems that you can help [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54125451/how-to-draw-a-shape-on-top-of-a-playing-video-by-clicking-a-mouse-button-in-open) Please have a look!

Answer (score 2):

This example from the opencv sample directory  allows you to draw an arbitrary rectangle in an image and select the ROI:

https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/samples/python/mouse_and_match.py

You can easily add alternatives to draw circles or polygons instead, e.g. by pressing a letter first.