# How to draw customized ROI and covert everything within that ROI as a binary mask

Tags: python

I want to draw some random ROIs on my image and convert it to a binary mask (similar as h = drawfreehand;          BW = createMask(h) in Matlab). Could any one give an idea? I tried code here: [How to make a free hand shape(random) on an image in python using opencv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36381684/how-to-make-a-free-hand-shaperandom-on-an-image-in-python-using-opencv).

But it only draw ROI but not generating/saving mask.

[How to make a free hand shape(random) on an image in python using opencv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36381684/how-to-make-a-free-hand-shaperandom-on-an-image-in-python-using-opencv).

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take your time to follow the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and consider that we normally answer to specific and detailed questions. We don't provide tutorials or solutions to questions like "I'd like to know how to do ___", and we can only really answer to questions that provide a valid [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (emphasis on *both* minimal *and* reproducible).

Comment: Please also include all relevant information as text in your question, do not link to other pages or embed images of your code/data/errors.